# PYTHONPATH Instead of Lambda Layers

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have 5-6 Python Files which are used across  multiple lambdas.

Currently I have created a Lambda Layer and added those files in the layer
and was able to import those files and lambdas were working fine.

Now, I have a requirement where I need to remove Lambda Layers and add Python Path.

I had never done this, Not able to find any examples.

It will be helpful If I get any Examples.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why not using the Lambda layer? Can you explain? It does not make sense.
2. You should pack the ' 5-6 Python Files' with the zip that contains the lambda. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-package.html).

Comment: 1.Layers add an extra layer of complexity that is not needed in a mono repo that contains multiple lambdas.
2.We view layers as libraries that should be shared across the organization among multiple repos. In this scenario the functionality is specific to the micro services in the mono repo.